# Error While Opening Django Shell - Python Interactive Window in Visual Studio

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

I just wanna mention that i'm just learning python & django so i'm a newbie and i need help.
Sorry if my question is dumb.

Here is my problem -
I was following the lesson - https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/developing-websites-using-python-and-django-11415?l=uw7LHeEJB_5304300477

And i tried opening the python interactive window by Right Clicking On DatabaseFun (My project name from solution explorer) > Python > Open Django Shell

And the Django Management Console -DatabaseFun windows opens up with error :

" Python interactive window. Type $help for a list of commands.
An internal error has occurred in the Interactive window.  Please restart Visual Studio. "

And the Django Management Console -DatabaseFun window seems to be disconnected

Additional Details - 
I've installed Python 3.5 - 32bit
Visual Studio 2015

Screenshots -
[View post on imgur.com](//imgur.com/a/qun6E)

Please Help , I'm struck for almost 10hours.

Comment: Personal opinion mildly set: I would consider using some other ide.

Comment: Even i want to ..  but considering the course(MVA) i'm learning from i need Visual Studio.

Comment: Understand. Is there a certification associated with this or just for tutorial? There is an excellent official tutrial also. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: There is no certification, the way they teach got me into it. Okay, let me drop it and shift the gears. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the error seems to be with the PTVS 2.2 as suggested by a github member i updated it to PTVS 2.2.2 which was released few days ago and the error disappeared.

https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/releases/tag/v2.2.2

Just wanna post this answer so that it may be useful for someone (haven't seen many answers for Visual Studio errors) .

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if i don't really answer your question but i suggest that you change the tools you are using.

IMO Visual Studio is far from good to code in python.
If you're a beginner and really want to use an IDE you could try PyCharm otherwise, a simple text-editor (SublimeText, Vim, Emacs) and a command-line are all you need.

You'll learn more, and will get rid of bug caused by your IDE (like the one you're having now).

Comment: Yea , i'm going to shift to ubuntu as suggested by many experts . But i want to complete this course, at least until then i need Visual Studio . I would appreciate some help. Thanks